# A question about equivariant sheaves

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Suppose we have an G-equivariant sheav $\mathcal F$ on a smooth variety $X$. Can we split $\mathcal F$ as sum of eigensheaves? (I have seen this for structure sheaf but not sure if we can do it for any G-equivariant sheaf). Any reference please.

Comment: What is $G$, and what do you call an eigensheaf?

Comment: G is any finite group. For eigensheaves please see equation 5 on page 2 of the following paper: http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.252.597&rep=rep1&type=pdf

Comment: That paper is about *abelian* groups. Is your group abelian?

Comment: My group is Abelian. But is it true for non-Abelian groups?

Comment: Of course not, already when $X$ is a point. When you ask a question here, try to describe precisely the problem you are considering. For instance, does $G$ act on $X$?

Comment: @abx: is that answer to non-Abelian case or for any finite group?

Comment: @AG.  The result is false, even for Abelian sheaves, even for a point.  Let $G$ be $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$.  Let $X$ be $\text{Spec}(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})$.  Let $F$ be $\mathcal{O}^{\oplus 2}$.  Let a generator of $G$ act by the matrix $$\left[ \begin{array}{cc} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 \end{array} \right].$$